# FastAI Segmentation Problem: Updating Model Weights with custom Item- and LabelList

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation, fast-ai

This might be a stupid question as nobody on fastai is trying to answer it. If it is one you can go ahead and tell me but also please tell me the answer, because right now I am completely lost.

I am currently working on a U-Net model for the segmentation of cells in microscopy images. Due to class imbalances and to amplify the importance of cell boundaries, I calculated a pixelwise weightmap for each image that I pass into fastai. Therefore I created a new ItemBase class to save labels and weights together:

```py
class WeightedLabels(ItemBase):
"""
Custom ItemBase to store and process labels and pixelwise weights together.
Also handling the target_size of the labels.
"""

def __init__(self, lbl: Image, wgt: Image, target_size: Tuple = None):
    self.lbl, self.wgt = lbl, wgt
    self.obj, self.data = (lbl, wgt), [lbl.data, wgt.data]

    self.target_size = target_size

...
```

I use extensive augmentation, like elastic deformation, mirroring and rotations on both weights and labels, as well as the original image. I determine the Loss with a custom Cross-entropy loss function that uses the weights to get the weighted loss for each pixel and averages them.

My problem is, that I do not get a very good performace. I have the feeling that might be because of fastai trying to predict the weights as well. My questions are:

1. Am I right to assume my model tries to predict both?
2. If so, how do I tell the learner what to use for updating the layers and to only predict part of my labels, while still applying augmentation to both?

Here's the code for how I implemented my custom LabelList and my custom ItemList:

```py
class CustomSegmentationLabelList(ImageList):
"'Item List' suitable for WeightedLabels containing labels and pixelweights"
_processor = vision.data.SegmentationProcessor

def __init__(self,
             items: Iterator,
             wghts = None,
             classes: Collection = None,
             target_size: Tuple = None,
             loss_func=CrossEntropyFlat(axis=1),
             **kwargs):

    super().__init__(items, **kwargs)
    self.copy_new.append('classes')
    self.copy_new.append('wghts')
    self.classes, self.loss_func, self.wghts = classes, loss_func, wghts
    self.target_size = target_size

def open(self, fn):
    res = io.imread(fn)
    res = pil2tensor(res, np.float32)
    return Image(res)

def get(self, i):
    fn = super().get(i)
    wt = self.wghts[i]
    return WeightedLabels(fn, self.open(wt), self.target_size)

def reconstruct(self, t: Tensor):
    return WeightedLabels(Image(t[0]), Image(t[1]), self.target_size)

class CustomSegmentationItemList(ImageList):
"'ItemList' suitable for segmentation with pixelwise weighted loss"
_label_cls, _square_show_res = CustomSegmentationLabelList, False

def label_from_funcs(self, get_labels: Callable, get_weights: Callable,
                     label_cls: Callable = None, classes=None,
                     target_size: Tuple = None, **kwargs) -> 'LabelList':
    "Get weights and labels from two functions. Saves them in a CustomSegmentationLabelList"
    kwargs = {}
    wghts = [get_weights(o) for o in self.items]
    labels = [get_labels(o) for o in self.items]

    if target_size:
        print(
            f'Masks will be cropped to {target_size}. Choose \'target_size \\= None \' to keep initial size.')
    else:
        print(f'Masks will not be cropped.')

    y = CustomSegmentationLabelList(
        labels, wghts, classes, target_size, path=self.path)
    res = self._label_list(x=self, y=y)
    return res
```

Also here the part, where I initiate my databunch object:

```py
data = (CustomSegmentationItemList.from_df(img_df,IMG_PATH, convert_mode=IMAGE_TYPE)
  .split_by_rand_pct(valid_pct=(1/N_SPLITS),seed=SEED)
  .label_from_funcs(get_labels, get_weights, target_size=MASK_SHAPE, classes = array(['background','cell']))
  .transform(tfms=tfms, tfm_y=True)
  .databunch(bs=BATCH_SIZE))
```

I use the regular learner, where I pass in my U-Net model, the data, my loss function and some additional arguments that shouldn't really matter here. When trying to apply my model, after training it, it gives me two identical output tensors. I assume that one is probably for the labels and the other for the weights. Both have the following dimensions: (WxHxC). I do not understand why this is happening, because my model is supposed to only have one output in form of (WxHxC). If this happens during prediction, this probably also happens during training. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Is this for the Kaggle PANDA challenge? 

Comment: @dumbPy no it's for my thesis